# Start a group of Virtual Machines in Virtualbox

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox

I cannot locate the command on **VBoxManage** or **VBoxHeadless** that will start a group of VM's in headless mode. Is there such an option?

I want to start from the command line a group of vm's without having to start individually every VM.

I stumbled upon [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/creating_and_using_vm_groups) but the flag --groups is not working in my case.

```
VBoxManage startvm  --type headless --groups "My Group"
```

> Syntax error: unknown option: --groups

The only way to start the group in headless mode is from the VirtualBox UI

Comment: Where do you look? Your question is not very informative. I bet you can tell us a lot more about the setup: what is the host OS? What have you tried?

Comment: @SPRBRN I edited the question, I thought that this info was irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

See [**Creating and using VM Groups in VirtualBox**](https://blogs.oracle.com/fatbloke/entry/creating_and_using_vm_groups)

> With VirtualBox 4.2 we introduced the Groups feature which allows you to organize and manage your guest virtual machines collectively, rather than individually.
>
> Groups are quite a powerful concept and there are a few nice features you may not have discovered yet, so here's a bit more information about groups, and how they can be used....